# Не получается решить задачу из учебника Меньшикова на языке C#. Помогите

Tags: c#, олимпиада

В декартовой системе координат на плоскости заданы координаты вершин треугольника и ещё одной точки. Определить, принадлежит ли эта точка треугольнику.

**Входные данные**: В четырёх строках находятся пары чисел - координаты точек. Числа в первых трёх строках - это координаты вершин треугольника, в четвёртой строке - координаты тестируемой точки. Координаты вершин - целые числа, для любой точки выполняются следующие условия: -10 000 <= x, y <= 10 000.

**Выходные данные:** Вывести слово "In", если точка находится внутри треугольника, или "Out" - если снаружи.

**Пример 1:

Входные данные:**
-2 -2
3 1
0 1
0 0

**Выход:**
In

**Пример 2:

Входные данные:**
-2 -2
3 1
0 1
2 -2

**Выходные данные:**
Out

Прошу решить только на языке **C#.**

Comment: А для чего второе условие здесь `if ((l >= 0) && (m <= 1))`? И почему только один x-компонент проверяется вместо полноценного получения коэффициента разложения вектора по базису?

Comment: Console.Readline возвращает string. Зачем конвертировать в string?

Comment: Ну кажется просто. Нужно по формуле Герона посчитать площадь треугольника и площадь треугольников образованных точкой (в качестве вершины) и каждой стороной треугольника (в качестве противоположной стороны треугольнику). Всего 3 новых треугольника. Если площадь треугольника совпадает  с суммой 3 вновь построеных, то точка внутри теугольника, иначе снаружи

Comment: Roman Ozhegov, так то оно так, но весь вопрос в реализации) Спасибо за совет, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Point
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Point a = GetPoint();
    Point b = GetPoint();
    Point c = GetPoint();
    Point toCheck = GetPoint();
    bool isIn = IsPointInTriangle(a, b, c, toCheck);
    if(isIn)
        Console.WriteLine("In");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Out");
    Console.Read();
}

private static Point GetPoint()
{
    Point p = new Point();
    Console.Write("X = ");
    p.X = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Y = ");
    p.Y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    return p;
}


private static double GetTriangleArea(Point a, Point b, Point c)
{
    return Math.Abs((a.X - c.X) * (b.Y - c.Y) + (b.X - c.X) * (c.Y - a.Y));
}

private static bool IsPointInTriangle(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point p)
{
    double trArea = GetTriangleArea(a, b, c);//площадь основного треугольника

    double trArea2 = GetTriangleArea(a, b, p);//площади треугольника, образованного из 2 точек основного
    double trArea3 = GetTriangleArea(a, p, c);//и точки, которая проверяется на принадлежность
    double trArea4 = GetTriangleArea(b, p, c);//к треугольнику

    return trArea == trArea2 + trArea3 + trArea4;// если площади образованных треугольников равны, то точка в треугольнике
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, слегка подправил ввод данных и синтаксис, и все на отлично заработало. Понятный и хороший код.