# Лежит ли точка в треугольнике

Tags: python, python-3.x, геометрия, pygame

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я занимаюсь разработкой приложения для редактирования изображений, и мне понадобилась функция выбора треугольника.

Я сделал простое вычисление по минимальным и максимальным координатам, как на первом рисунке.
Минус в том, что когда я нажимаю на весь прямоугольник, выбирается треугольник.

Мне хотелось бы сделать, как на втором рисунке. Как это сделать?

Upd:
Данные для проверки:
Позиция мыши,
Коордикаты, на которых расположены вершины треугольника, абсолютно любые.

Мне просто нужно, чтобы если позиция мыши вышла за пределы треугольника(рис.2), то треугольник не выбирался.
На данный момент у меня реализована схема, как на рисунке 1.
То есть вычисляюстя минимальные и максимальные позиции x и y.
Вот как это выглядит:

- self.xv и self.yv - это позиции вершин по х и у.

```
self.x=min(self.xv)
self.y=min(self.yv)
self.x1=max(self.xv)
self.y1=max(self.yv)
w=-self.x+self.x1
h=-self.y+self.y1
```

Мне не особо нравится это, поэтому я стал нуждаться в проверке "находится ли позиция мыши в треуоольнике"

Comment: При чем здесь "вычисление площади треугольника"?

Comment: чтобы правильно вынести вердикт: "выбран" или "не выбран"

Comment: Причём тут площадь? Вам надо [проверить, лежит ли точка в треугольнике](https://www.cyberforum.ru/algorithms/thread144722.html)

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, информацию: какие входные данные? Есть координаты вершин?

Comment: Может, быть. Но мне нужен ответ на python.

Comment: В принципе, зная теорему Пифагора задачу можно довольно быстро решить и оформить в питон.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Переписал формулу [из этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1126891/201445) (спасибо **nörbörnën**).

В примере ниже, позиция курсора мышки сравнивается с положением треугольника и выводится надпись **Collision!** если курсор мышки находится в треугольнике.

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c4c0bbfe01ee5caef1989756a89e1bd1dd13fe67/pygame__examples/is_point_in_triangle.py#L27)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import sys

import pygame


BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)


@dataclass
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float


def get_triangle_area(a: Point, b: Point, c: Point) -> float:
    return abs((a.x - c.x) * (b.y - c.y) + (b.x - c.x) * (c.y - a.y))


def is_point_in_triangle(a: Point, b: Point, c: Point, p: Point) -> bool:
    tr_area = get_triangle_area(a, b, c)  # Площадь основного треугольника

    tr_area2 = get_triangle_area(a, b, p)  # Площади треугольника, образованного из 2 точек основного
    tr_area3 = get_triangle_area(a, p, c)  # и точки, которая проверяется на принадлежность
    tr_area4 = get_triangle_area(b, p, c)  # к треугольнику

    # Если площади образованных треугольников равны, то точка в треугольнике
    return tr_area == tr_area2 + tr_area3 + tr_area4


pygame.init()

color = BLACK
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
mouse_pos = Point(0, 0)

# Triangle
a, b, c = Point(100, 100), Point(100, 400), Point(500, 500)

fnt = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mouse_pos.x, mouse_pos.y = event.pos
            break

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # This draws a triangle using the polygon command
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, BLACK, [[a.x, a.y], [b.x, b.y], [c.x, c.y]], 5)

    if is_point_in_triangle(a, b, c, mouse_pos):
        color = BLACK
    else:
        color = WHITE

    text = fnt.render("Collision!", True, color)
    screen.blit(text, (260, 20))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```